# Messages in kernel log during boot, Warning: CPU, amdgpu_suspend

Tags: boot, kernel, amdgpu

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 in an Acer laptop with CPU AMD A12-9720P and hybrid graphics (AMD Radeon R7 + dedicated AMD Radeon Rx 540.
If I look at Ksystemlog after booting, I always find this in the kernel log:

```
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 53 at /build/linux-lZKWha/linux-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/amdgpu_dm/amdgpu_dm.c:601 dm_suspend+0x53/0x60 [amdgpu]
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  Modules linked in: cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 arc4 joydev uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev media edac_mce_amd kvm_amd kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_realtek ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic pcbc snd_hda_codec_hdmi aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec acer_wmi snd_hda_core sparse_keymap snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm serio_raw hid_multitouch snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event wmi_bmof snd_rawmidi ath10k_pci fam15h_power k10temp ath10k_core snd_seq ath btusb rtsx_pci_ms btrtl btbcm btintel mac80211 memstick bluetooth snd_seq_device ecdh_generic snd_timer cfg80211 snd shpchp soundcore tpm_crb mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   hid_generic usbhid amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 amdgpu rtsx_pci_sdmmc chash i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper i2c_piix4 syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ahci fb_sys_fops r8169 libahci mii drm rtsx_pci i2c_hid video wmi hid
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  CPU: 3 PID: 53 Comm: kworker/3:1 Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  Hardware name: Acer Aspire A515-41G/Wartortle_BS, BIOS V1.06 09/27/2017
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  Workqueue: pm pm_runtime_work
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  RIP: 0010:dm_suspend+0x53/0x60 [amdgpu]
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  RSP: 0018:ffffa19e810bfc58 EFLAGS: 00010282
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f7b891e0000 RCX: 0000000000000000
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000286 RDI: 0000000000000286
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  RBP: ffffa19e810bfc60 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 000000000000000f R12: ffff8f7b891e0000
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  R13: ffffffffc074d9a0 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0000000000000000
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f7b9ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  CR2: 00007f8e1c028248 CR3: 0000000211f5c000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  Call Trace:
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   amdgpu_suspend+0x6b/0x170 [amdgpu]
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   amdgpu_device_suspend+0x1f7/0x3c0 [amdgpu]
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? vga_switcheroo_runtime_resume+0x60/0x60
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   amdgpu_pmops_runtime_suspend+0x57/0xd0 [amdgpu]
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   pci_pm_runtime_suspend+0x64/0x180
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? vga_switcheroo_runtime_resume+0x60/0x60
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   vga_switcheroo_runtime_suspend+0x29/0xa0
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   __rpm_callback+0xca/0x210
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   rpm_callback+0x24/0x80
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? vga_switcheroo_runtime_resume+0x60/0x60
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   rpm_suspend+0x137/0x640
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   pm_runtime_work+0x75/0xa0
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   process_one_work+0x1de/0x410
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   worker_thread+0x32/0x410
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   kthread+0x121/0x140
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
08/06/18 12:16  kernel   ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  Code: 00 00 00 75 26 48 8b 7b 08 e8 5a 7e e5 ff 48 8b bb 28 92 00 00 48 89 83 90 a9 00 00 be 08 00 00 00 e8 92 57 08 00 31 c0 5b 5d c3 <0f> 0b eb d6 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 
08/06/18 12:16  kernel  ---[ end trace 67c59efbaa6a6bd9 ]---
```

This is what is before:

```
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4518] NetworkManager (version 1.10.6) is starting... (for the first time)
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4519] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4879] manager[0x5587c26b0060]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4880] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4941] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4941] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "fabio-Aspire-A515-41G"
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4946] dns-mgr[0x5587c26c9170]: init: dns=systemd-resolved, rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4965] rfkill3: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.3/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver ath10k_pci)
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.4968] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/acer-wmi/rfkill/rfkill1) (platform driver acer-wmi)
08/06/18 12:16  systemd Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
```

And this is after:

```
08/06/18 12:16  NetworkManager  <info>  [1528453001.5155] manager[0x5587c26b0060]: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
```

It seems this makes booting around 1 minute slower.
What's the meaning of all this? Can it be solved? Or is it a bug I have to report somewhere?